# Shortcut for dash and ccsm menu

Tags: shortcuts, keys

I'm new to Ubuntu and was looking in the `ccsm`. I think I have disabled something as now there is no apps/programs/icons down the side and no menu across the top of screen to minimise or exit a program.

How do I get back to the dash and `ccsm` menu if I can see it on the screen? Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal with the following shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> then type the `ccsm` command:

[image]

It should open CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Ubuntu version **prior to 14.04**, you may consider a "factory reset" of Unity. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
unity --reset
```

Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

If you are running **14.04**, or the above method doesn't work, you can also completely wipe your Compiz configuration. Open a terminal (or even better, login from a TTY) and then type:

```
 rm -rf ~/.compiz ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Then log in again. It should be back to the defaults.

Comment: It won't work on 14.04 (ERROR: the reset option is now deprecated
)

Comment: You are right. I will update my answer with another possible solution.